# XAML Loading Animation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, animation

I'm trying to create a loading animation in XAML. I know about ProgressRing, but for product branding we're trying to use our own loading circle.

I'd like to achieve the same functionality as ProgressRing (triggered by a boolean), but with my own pattern.

Below is the storyboard I've used to get the circles to do one full rotation, but I'm getting confused on how to activate it via boolean and also how to make it a continuous.

For our application, we will also have multiple of these loading icons on each page, and we will need to trigger them separately.

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="SpinAnimation" Completed="Spin_Complete">
            <DoubleAnimation From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FirstCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.1" From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SecondCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.2" From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ThirdCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.3" From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FourthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.4" From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FifthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.5" From="1" To=".3" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SixthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.1" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FirstCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.2" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SecondCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.3" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ThirdCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.4" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FourthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.5" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FifthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:.6" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SixthCircle"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd just go a style up a [ProgressRing style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709924.aspx) so then you can just do `<ProgressRing Style="{StaticResource YourNewProgressRingStyle"/>` or set it as the default template, and then you and anyone using it in the future don't need to remember new tricks and can fire it up the exact same way you would with any ProgressRing

Comment: Thanks, Chris. We're using MahApps.Metro in our WPF application, so I grabbed the ProgressRing control from there as well as the ProgressRing theme, stripped them down, and made a similar loading animation.

Comment: ah ok, I assumed you were doing store apps not wpf, but good deal, glad you got your remedy. If you run into any hiccups or are not getting the exact end result you're after let me know and we'll get you sorted. Cheers